# proving implications involving limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

> Throughout this question, let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence whose limit is $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and such that $x_n \neq a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  And let $F$ be a function which is defined on an open interval containing $a$.  Determine, with explanation, which of the following statements are true and which are false.
>
> a) If $\lim_{x\to a} F(x) = L$, then for all $\{x_n\}$ (which tends to $a$ and $x_n \neq a$), $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_{2n}) = L$.
>
> b) If there exists $\{x_n\}$ (which tends to $a$ and $x_n \neq a)$ [such that] $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_{2n}) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a} F(x_n) = L$.
>
> c) If for all $\{x_n\}$ (which tends to $a$ and $x_n \neq a$), $\lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_{2n}) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a}F(x) = L$.

[image: My attempt]

How would I prove these statements?

If anybody could point out my mistakes in my answers I'd appreciate it. I'm not really sure how to go about solving these questions.

Comment: You've employed circular logic in your answer to b)

Comment: The level of rigor to put into your answers depends on your course/book's definition of limit.  What definition are you using for limit of a function at a point or limit of a sequence at $\infty$? (In other words, is this an calculus class or an analysis class?)

Comment: Your proof of $(a) $ is correct, but next two parts require the use of definition of limit.

Comment: Ah Ok. We are using the Epsilon-delta definition of a limit in class. So how would a proof of B (or disproof) look like? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, would any of the above statements be false? If so, why would they be false? Thanks.